# Can O(k * n) be considered as linear complexity (O(n))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

When talking about complexity in general, things like O(3n) tend to be simplified to O(n) and so on. This is merely theoretical, so how does complexity work in reality? Can O(3n) also be simplified to O(n)?

For example, if a task implies that solution must be in O(n) complexity and in our code we have 2 times linear search of an array, which is O(n) + O(n). So, in reality, would that solution be considered as linear complexity or not fast enough?

Note that this question is asking about real implementations, not theoretical. I'm already aware that O(n) + O(n) is simplified to O(n)?

Comment: What do you mean by "in reality"? O notation has a very specific definition that tells you exactly what's equivalent and what isn't. That's the reality.

Comment: It's important to understand that the Big-O notation does not provide the number of instructions being executed, but the growth rate of the algorithm.

Comment: @sepp2k You're right. When talking about theoretical complexity, O(2n) is equal to O(n), right? However, in real world, O(2n) is much different than O(n) and so my question asks if it would be realistical to simplify O(2n) or any O(kn) to O(n).

Comment: "O(2n) is much different than O(n) [...] No, it is not accurate to say this, and I think it hints you may fundamentally misunderstand the Big-O notation.

Comment: @leonz O(n) is the same as O(2n) by definition. What I believe you're trying to say is that "doing twice the amount of work takes longer than only doing it once". That's true of course, but if you want to say that, say that. Don't use terms that mean something else and then pretend that they mean what you want them to mean "in reality". They don't.

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind that O(f(n)) does not give you the amount of real-world time that something takes: only the rate of growth as n grows. O(n) only indicates that if n doubles, the runtime doubles as well, which lumps functions together that take one second per iteration or one millennium per iteration.

For this reason, O(n) + O(n) and O(2n) are both equivalent to O(n), which is *the set of functions of linear complexity*, and which should be sufficient for your purposes.

Though an algorithm that takes arbitrary-sized inputs will often want the most optimal function as represented by O(f(n)), an algorithm that *grows faster* (e.g. O(n²)) may still be faster in practice, especially when the data set size n is limited or fixed in practice. However, learning to reason about O(f(n)) representations can help you compose algorithms to have a predictable—optimal for your use-case—upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as `k` is a *constant*, you can write *O(kn) = O(n)*.

---

The intuition behind is that the *constant k* doesn't increase with the size of the input space and at some point will be incomparably small to *n*, so it doesn't have much influence on the overall complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - as long as the number *k* of array searches is not affected by the input size, even for inputs that are too big to be possible in practice, *O(kn) = O(n)*. The main idea of the *O* notation is to emphasize how the computation time increases with the size of the input, and so constant factors that stay the same no matter how big the input is aren't of interest.

An example of an *incorrect* way to apply this is to say that you can perform selection sort in linear time because you can only fit about one billion numbers in memory, and so selection sort is merely one billion array searches. However, with an ideal computer with infinite memory, your algorithm would not be able to handle more than one billion numbers, and so it is not a correct sorting algorithm (algorithms must be able to handle arbitrarily large inputs unless you specify a limit as a part of the problem statement); it is merely a correct algorithm for sorting up to one billion numbers.

(As a matter of fact, once you put a limit on the input size, most algorithms will become constant-time because for all inputs within your limit, the algorithm will solve it using at most the amount of time that is required for the biggest / most difficult input.)